# How to get the clicked row from a table in jsp

Tags: javascript, database, jsp

I've a table in a .jsp listing Vinyls, I want to add a button to every row to click and do an action with the information of the vinyl listed.

This is the code generator of the table

```
<%
    for (int i = 0; i < listaVinilos.size(); i++) {
    Vinilo vin = listaVinilos.get(i);
%>
<tr>
    <td><button class="icon fa-plus-circle" onclick="anadirVinilo()"></button></td>
    <td><img src="<%=vin.getImagen()%>" alt="" height="100" width="100"/></td>
    <td id="idTitulo<%=i%>"><%=vin.getTitulo()%></td>
    <td id="idAutor<%=i%>"><%=vin.getAutor()%></td>
    <td><%=vin.getDiscografica()%></td>
    <td><%=vin.getGenero()%></td><td><%=vin.getFecha()%></td>
    <td><%=vin.getRPM()%></td>
    <td><%=vin.getNumLanzamiento()%></td>
<tr/>
<%
    }
%>
```

I've thought about creating a function `anadirVinilo()` and identifying the author and title with ID to use later in the function but I don't know how to tell the function what row I am clicking.

Answer (score 0):

See if the below code suits your needs.

```
<%
    for (int i = 0; i < listaVinilos.size(); i++) {
    Vinilo vin = listaVinilos.get(i);
%>
<tr>
    <td><button class="icon fa-plus-circle"   onclick="anadirVinilo('<%=vin.getTitulo()%>','<%=vin.getAutor()%>')"></button></td>
    <td><img src="<%=vin.getImagen()%>" alt="" height="100" width="100"/></td>
    <td id="idTitulo<%=i%>"><%=vin.getTitulo()%></td>
    <td id="idAutor<%=i%>"><%=vin.getAutor()%></td>
    <td><%=vin.getDiscografica()%></td>
    <td><%=vin.getGenero()%></td><td><%=vin.getFecha()%></td>
    <td><%=vin.getRPM()%></td>
    <td><%=vin.getNumLanzamiento()%></td>
<tr/>
<%
    }
%>
```

And you will define the function like this:

function anadirVinilo(title,author){

Your logic here with tiltle, author or any other parameters you pass!

}